# Using DatePicker which shows me `Invalid date!`

Tags: angular

In the`edit-purchasable-securities` template, I have a `Date` input, I want to use the `DatePicker` because I find it looks more aesthetically pleasing.

[image]

I add `BsDatepickerModule` , my problem is that I have a weird message `Invalid date!`, I really don't understand where the problem comes from?

Why is the date `24/05/2017` no longer displayed?

[image]

Do you know where the problem could come from? I prefer to share the whole component with you,

**edit-purchasable-securities.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    ModalModule,
    BsDatepickerModule,
    PipesModule,
    TranslocoModule
  ],
  declarations: [EditPurchasableSecuritiesComponent],
  providers: [EditPurchasableSecuritiesService]
})
export class EditPurchasableSecuritiesModule { }
```

**edit-purchasable-securities.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class EditPurchasableSecuritiesService {
  
  private readonly api: string = environment.api;

  @Select(AuthState.language) language$!: Observable<string>;
  
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private datePipe: NekFormatDatePipe
    ) 
    { }

  editPurchasableSecuritiesManagement(svm: string,  params: { from?: string } = {}): Observable<PurchasableSecuritieResponse> {
    return this.http.post<PurchasableSecuritieResponse>(this.api + `/WNEKTITC`, {
      SECURITYSEARCH: {
        FROM: params.from || 'NEK',
        SVM: parseInt(svm),
      },
   

    }, );
    
  }

  updatePurchasableSecuritiesManagement(svm: string, risk: string, datedeb: Date, datefin: Date, min: number, max: number,
    sipminimum: number, sipmaximum: number): Observable<PurchasableResponse> {
    return this.http.post<PurchasableResponse>(this.api + `/WNEKTITM`, {
      IN_TITRE: {
        SVM: parseInt(svm),
        AANBOD: {
          ACTION: "MOD",
          RISK: risk,
          DATDEB: this.datePipe.transform(datedeb, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
          DATFIN: datefin,
          MIN: min,
          MAX: max,
          SIPMINIMUM: sipminimum,
          SIPMAXIMUM: sipmaximum,
        }
      }
    });
  }
  
}
```

**edit-purchasable-securities.component.ts**

```
export class EditPurchasableSecuritiesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject < void > ();

  svm: string; 
  risk: string;
  datedeb: Date;
  datefin: Date; 
  min: number; 
  max: number; 
  sipminimum: number;
  sipmaximum: number; 
  
  TIT: Tit[] = [];

  constructor(
    private service: EditPurchasableSecuritiesService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
    private router: Router

    ) { }
  
    ngOnInit(): void {
      let svm: string | null;
      svm = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('svm');
      if (!svm) {
        this.goBack();
        return;
      } 
      this.svm = svm;
      this.editPurchasableSecuritiesManagement(this.svm);
      
    }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }

  editPurchasableSecuritiesManagement(svm: string): void {
    this.service.editPurchasableSecuritiesManagement(this.svm).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
     
        this.TIT = res.TIT;
        this.risk = res.TIT[0].AANBOD.RISK;
        this.datedeb = res.TIT[0].AANBOD.DATEVALID_DEBUT;
        this.datefin = res.TIT[0].AANBOD.DATEVALID_FIN;
        this.min = res.TIT[0].AANBOD.QTTE_MIN;
        this.max = res.TIT[0].AANBOD.QTTE_MAX;
        this.sipminimum = res.TIT[0].AANBOD.SIPMINIMUM;
        this.sipmaximum = res.TIT[0].AANBOD.SIPMAXIMUM;
  
      }
    });
  }

  updatePurchasableSecuritiesManagement(): void {
    this.service.updatePurchasableSecuritiesManagement(this.svm, this.risk, this.datedeb, this.datefin, this.min, this.max,
      this.sipminimum, this.sipmaximum).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    ).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.RETURNCODE === ApiResponseCodeEnum.Ok) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['functional-management/list-purchasable-securities']);   
        }); 
      }
    });
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

}
```

**edit-purchasable-securities.component.html**

```
<span style="margin-right: 5px;">De</span>
<input id="datedeb" name="datedeb" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="datedeb" style="width: 25%" bsDatepicker required>
```